# How to maximize this equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I am trying to maximize $P = 20q_a - 2q_a^2 + 16q_b-2q_b^2 – 1/4 (q_a + q_b)^2$, a profit equation, function of two separate quantities of products. I thought that what I need to do is to set both derivatives =0 and find where that equation holds for both variables, but I am having some trouble. Here's my work:
$dP/dq_a = 20 – 4q_a – 1/2 (q_a + q_b) = 0$ 
$dP/dq_b = 16 – 4q_b – 1/2 (q_a + q_b)  = 0$
$4 – 4q_a +4q_b = 0$
$4 = 4 (q_a – q_b)$
$q_a = q_b + 1.$

As you can see from the last equation, I get $q_a = q_b + 1$, but when I plug a pair of 1, 0 ($q_a$ and $q_b$) into the derivative equations, I do not get 0's, so I guess I made a mistake somewhere (wolfram alpha gives a definitive answer). Please help, thanks!

Comment: The partial derivatives are
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial q_{a}}=20-\frac{9}{2}q_{a}-\frac{1}{2}q_{b}$$
 $$\frac{\partial P}{\partial q_{b}}=16-\frac{9}{2}q_{b}-\frac{1}{2}q_{a},$$
and the solution of the system 
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
20-\frac{9}{2}q_{a}-\frac{1}{2}q_{b}=0 \\ 
16-\frac{9}{2}q_{b}-\frac{1}{2}q_{a}=0
\end{array}
\right. $$
    is $$q_{a}=\frac{41}{10},q_{b}=\frac{31}{10}.$$

Comment: Your subject line should say "How to maximize this function".  "Equation" is definitely not the right word; it's not an equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have at the end is essentially just $dP/dq_a-dP/dq_b=0$. This isn't equivalent to making both derivatives simultaneously zero: you've just made them both equal. But if they're both zero it means they're both equal, so you can at least *use* your last line to go further. Plug $q_a=q_b+1$ back into one of the original derivatives, set to $0$, and solve; then substitute back for $q_a$.

---

Also note that in the first place you might have been better off if you'd seen what you were working with is a linear system of equations. Setting both derivatives equal to zero is the same as saying:

$$\begin{pmatrix}4+1/2 & 1/2\\ 1/2 & 4+1/2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}q_a\\q_b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}20\\16\end{pmatrix}. $$
Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: anon: Thank you! I will do that.